# Why is the output of "canget(state(atdoor, onfloor, inmiddle, atwindow, hasnot), Plan)." in this program repeatedly returning as false?

Tags: prolog

For this assignment, I have to produce a program that determines the steps a fictional monkey needs to take in order to get a banana suspended from the ceiling. In order to grab the banana, it must push a box underneath it, climbing on top of the box for extra reach.

However, every time, when I input "?- canget(state(atdoor, onfloor, inmiddle, atwindow, hasnot), Plan).", it reads out as false, indicating that there's no way for the monkey to reach the banana.

This is blatantly untrue, as in any situation where the monkey starts on the floor, it should be able to  follow these steps.

1. Walk to the box's location.
2. Push the box to the banana's location.
3. Climb on top of the box.
4. Grab the banana.

There must be something wrong with the program, but I haven't been able to catch it, not even after an hour of poring over the code.

I've tried eliminating the comments, in case those are somehow connected to it.

```
cls :- write('\e[H\e[2J').

%state(Monkey location in the room, Monkey onbox/onfloor, boxlocation, banana location, has/hasnot banana)


%This causes the monkey to walk to the box. 

do( state(_, onfloor, M, _, hasnot),    
    the, monkey, walks, to, the, M, [], [],  
    state(M, onfloor, M, _, hasnot)).

%This causes the monkey to push the box to where the banana is. 

do( state(L, onfloor, L, M, hasnot),    
    the, monkey, pushes, the, box, to, the, M,
    state(M, onfloor, M, M, hasnot)).

%This causes the monkey to climb the box. 

do( state(L, onfloor, L, L, has),           
    the, monkey, climbs, the, box, [], [], [], 
    state(L, onbox, L, L, has)).


do( state(SharedLocation, onBox, SharedLocation, SharedLocation, hasnot)
    the, monkey, grabs, the, banana, [], [], [],
    state(SharedLocation, onBox, SharedLocation, SharedLocation, has)). %This causes the monkey to grab the banana. 




%canget(state) represents if the monkey can retrieve the banana from its current state. 
canget(state(_, _, _, _, has), []).  

%This states what the monkey should do in a non-ideal state. Namely, performing an action, and concatenating the appropriate sentence.
canget(State1, Plan):-                  
    do(State1, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, State2), 
    canget(State2, PartialPlan9),           
    add(A, PartialPlan1, PartialPlan2),     
    add(B, PartialPlan2, PartialPlan3), 
    add(C, PartialPlan3, PartialPlan4),
    add(D, PartialPlan4, PartialPlan5),
    add(E, PartialPlan5, PartialPlan6),
    add(F, PartialPlan6, PartialPlan7),
    add(G, PartialPlan7, PartialPlan8),
    add(H, PartialPlan8, PartialPlan9),
    add(".", PartialPlan9, Plan)).
```

When prolog runs, there are two errors that I haven't been able to eliminate. I'm not sure if  they're related, but here they are.

> ERROR: c:/users/(my account name)/documents/prolog files/monkey text problem.pl:26:3: Syntax error: Operator expected
>
> ERROR: c:/users/(my account name)/documents/prolog files/monkey text problem.pl:47:28: Syntax error: Illegal start of term

Instead of outputting false, the program should output what the list 'Plan', should be.

Comment: Thank you all for all the assistance provided. With your help, I managed to figure out what was going on, and got the program working!

Answer (score 0):

I've cleared errors and the warning issued about the singleton you'll see in last clause once the syntax has been amended:

```
Warning:    Singleton variables: [PartialPlan1]
```

but since the add/3 predicate is missing you need more effort to get it working. Anyway, the code is here

```erlang
cls :- write('\e[H\e[2J').

%state(Monkey location in the room, Monkey onbox/onfloor, boxlocation, banana location, has/hasnot banana)


%This causes the monkey to walk to the box. 

do( state(_, onfloor, M, _, hasnot),    
    the, monkey, walks, to, the, M, [], [],  
    state(M, onfloor, M, _, hasnot)).

%This causes the monkey to push the box to where the banana is. 

do( state(L, onfloor, L, M, hasnot),    
    the, monkey, pushes, the, box, to, the, M,
    state(M, onfloor, M, M, hasnot)).

%This causes the monkey to climb the box. 

do( state(L, onfloor, L, L, has),           
    the, monkey, climbs, the, box, [], [], [], 
    state(L, onbox, L, L, has)).


do( state(SharedLocation, onBox, SharedLocation, SharedLocation, hasnot),
    the, monkey, grabs, the, banana, [], [], [],
    state(SharedLocation, onBox, SharedLocation, SharedLocation, has)). %This causes the monkey to grab the banana. 




%canget(state) represents if the monkey can retrieve the banana from its current state. 
canget(state(_, _, _, _, has), []).  

%This states what the monkey should do in a non-ideal state. Namely, performing an action, and concatenating the appropriate sentence.
canget(State1, Plan):-                  
    do(State1, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, State2), 
    canget(State2, PartialPlan1),           
    add(A, PartialPlan1, PartialPlan2),     
    add(B, PartialPlan2, PartialPlan3), 
    add(C, PartialPlan3, PartialPlan4),
    add(D, PartialPlan4, PartialPlan5),
    add(E, PartialPlan5, PartialPlan6),
    add(F, PartialPlan6, PartialPlan7),
    add(G, PartialPlan7, PartialPlan8),
    add(H, PartialPlan8, PartialPlan9),
    add(".", PartialPlan9, Plan).
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not have your `add` predicate, so I modified the definitions of actions in each one of the `do` clauses.

Explanations of the changes that I made are identified by `==>` in the code.

```
%state(Monkey location in the room, Monkey onbox/onfloor, boxlocation, banana location, has/hasnot banana)

%This causes the monkey to walk to the box.
% ==> You have to capture fact that the banana does not change location
% ==> when the monkey walks, hence the variable B. Also to make progress
% ==> L and M must not be the same location.
do(state(L, onfloor, M, B, hasnot),
   the_monkey_walks_to(M),  
   state(M, onfloor, M, B, hasnot)) :-
    L \= M.

%This causes the monkey to push the box to where the banana is. 
% ==> To make progress L and M must not be the same location.
do(state(L, onfloor, L, M, hasnot),    
   the_monkey_pushes_the_box_to_the(M),
   state(M, onfloor, M, M, hasnot)) :-
    L \= M.

%This causes the monkey to climb on the box. 
do(state(L, onfloor, L, L, hasnot),           
   the_monkey_climbs_on_the_box, 
   state(L, onbox, L, L, hasnot)).

%This causes the monkey to climb down the box.
% ==> This action was missing, causing the monkey to get stuck on the box.
do(state(L, onbox, L, L, hasnot),           
   the_monkey_climbs_down_the_box, 
   state(L, onfloor, L, L, hasnot)).

%This causes the monkey to grab the banana. 
% ==> You had a typo here, you have to use the atom `onbox` instead of `onBox`.
do(state(SharedLocation, onbox, SharedLocation, SharedLocation, hasnot),
   the_monkey_grabs_the_banana,
   state(SharedLocation, onbox, SharedLocation, SharedLocation, has)). 

%canget(state) represents if the monkey can retrieve the banana from its current state. 
canget(state(_, _, _, _, has), [], _).  

%This states what the monkey should do in a non-ideal state. Namely, performing an action, and concatenating the appropriate sentence.
% ==> You have to keep track of the previous states, for otherwise the plan could get
% ==> into an infinite loop.
canget(State1, [Action | PartialPlan1], PreviousStates):- 
    not(memberchk(State1, PreviousStates)),
    do(State1, Action, State2), 
    canget(State2, PartialPlan1, [State1 | PreviousStates]).
    %add(A, PartialPlan1, PartialPlan2),     
    %add(B, PartialPlan2, PartialPlan3), 
    %add(C, PartialPlan3, PartialPlan4),
    %add(D, PartialPlan4, PartialPlan5),
    %add(E, PartialPlan5, PartialPlan6),
    %add(F, PartialPlan6, PartialPlan7),
    %add(G, PartialPlan7, PartialPlan8),
    %add(H, PartialPlan8, PartialPlan9),
    %add(".", PartialPlan9, Plan).
```

Queryting for `canget(state(atdoor, onfloor, inmiddle, atwindow, hasnot), Plan, []).` yields:

```
Plan = [the_monkey_walks_to(inmiddle), the_monkey_pushes_the_box_to_the(atwindow), the_monkey_climbs_on_the_box, the_monkey_grabs_the_banana]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this has been explicitly pointed out by somebody already, but Prolog's error messages, though they may seem somewhat cryptic to Prolog newcomers, actually tell you what is wrong with the program (syntax-wise). At the very least, it helps to look at the (immediate area around the) precise position in the code that they refer to.

The error

> ERROR: c:/users/(my account name)/documents/prolog files/monkey text problem.pl:26:3: Syntax error: Operator expected

points you to the clause (line 26, column 3)

```
do( state(SharedLocation, onBox, SharedLocation, SharedLocation, hasnot)
    the, monkey, grabs, the, banana, [], [], [],
    state(SharedLocation, onBox, SharedLocation, SharedLocation, has)). %This causes the monkey to grab the banana.
```

or more precisely, the first occurrence of "`the`" in the second line of that clause. The message "`operator expected`" tells you that Prolog was expecting an operator (such as a comma) at this point, not an atom (such as "`the`"). If you look closely, you see that in the previous line (immediately before) indeed there is a comma missing after "`state(..., hasnot)`".

Similarly, the message

> ERROR: c:/users/(my account name)/documents/prolog files/monkey text problem.pl:47:28: Syntax error: Illegal start of term

points you to the last line

```
    add(".", PartialPlan9, Plan)).
```

of the very last clause, which has one closing parenthesis too many. Here, Prolog tried to read the "`Plan)`" part as one term, which has an "illegal start" because a closing "`)`" should always be preceded by some functor and an opening "`(`"; something like "`foo(Plan)`" for example would have been a legal term.